# Replace dot in a number

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace the dot in a number in Javascript with regular expression; if country_temp is, for example, 1.234, how can I put the value 1234 in country_temp2?
I have tried the following:

```
const country_temp2 = country_temp.replace(/[a-zA-Z]*\**\s*\./g, "")
but it's not working.
```

Edit: the original string is composed by characters, asterisk, a number and a dot
Sorry, but I have written in a very fast way.

Comment: `var country_temp2 = country_temp.replace(".","");`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
country_temp.replace(/\./g,'')
```